# Leaflet.PolylineOffset Polyline with offset is drawn on the inside of a polygon

Tags: polygon, leaflet, leaflet-plugins

I'm new in `Leaflet JS` and I'm using `Leaflet.PolylineOffset` in order to draw a polyline around my polygon:

```
L.polygon(coords, { fillColor: 'red', fillOpacity: 0.5, weight: 20, color: 'red', opacity: 0.5, fill: true}).addTo(map);
coords.push(coords[0]);
L.polyline(coords, { color: 'purple', weight: 2, opacity: 0.7, fill: false, offset: 10}).addTo(map);
```

The problem is that when the polygon was drawn to the left like

```
var coords= [
[27.40839959582344,-82.40601726602196],
[27.40859871554781,-82.40638191331237],
[27.40834938302612,-82.40652231229888]
];
```

it adds the offset polyline outside the polygon, and that's correct, but when the polygon was drawn to the right, the polyline with the same offset is drawn on the inside of the polygon.

```
var coords = [
[27.408016915801475,-82.40592313259484],
[27.408532896850133,-82.40536543657525],
[27.408179675316514,-82.40446844335956]
];
```

Is there a way to draw the polyline on the outside of the polygon for both situations?

Comment: That extra weight parameter in your polygon weight:20, is that necessary?

Comment: @ranggalawe What do you mean by my polygon extra weight?

Comment: Nothing, just to make sure map visual is clean. When changes of coordinates also change offset, the answer by @user30184 is most likely correct. As alternative to leaflet.Polyline offset, library such as turf.js >> https://turfjs.org/docs/#rewind maybe useful to get what you want. A safer way to get the offset line: first buffer the polygon e.g (https://turfjs.org/docs/#buffer) and then get the buffered line using https://turfjs.org/docs/#polygonToLine

Comment: If Leaflet accepts polygons in both way, maybe you could create a buffered polygon with a negative buffer distance and render just the outline of the buffered polygon. EDIT sorry, suggested already in the previous comment.

Comment: @user30184 I think I found a solution to my problem. I'm checking if the polygon is clockwise and if it is I'm making the offset negative

Comment: Did you really find solution yourselves or with the help of the answer? It's customary on GIS SE site to mark answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem. Also, how do you check if polygon is clockwise?

Comment: @TomazicM Oh... now I saw your comment regarding booleanClockwise. Sorry for that :( You are right :) I've used something similar

Comment: @TomazicM Can you, please add it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you found out,  offset depends on the order of line string coordinates, and as  @user30184 pointed out, this depends on order of liner ring coordinates that constitutes the polygon: clockwise or counterclockwise.

On possible way to check order of polygon coordinates is to use [turf.js](https://turfjs.org/) function `turf.booleanClockwise`. You can also use `turf.rewind` function to change coordinates order.

Answer (score 2):

See https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946

> 3.1.6.  Polygon
>
> To specify a constraint specific to Polygons, it is useful to
> introduce the concept of a linear ring:
>
> o  A linear ring is a closed LineString with four or more
> positions.
>
> o  The first and last positions are equivalent, and they MUST
> contain
> identical values; their representation SHOULD also be identical.
>
> o  A linear ring is the boundary of a surface or the boundary of a
> hole in a surface.
>
> o  A linear ring MUST follow the right-hand rule with respect to
> the
> area it bounds, i.e., exterior rings are counterclockwise, and
> holes are clockwise.

I think you should make sure that all the polygons have right winding order before using PolylineOffset. Maybe you can do that with https://github.com/mapbox/geojson-rewind

Comment: [turf.js](https://turfjs.org/) functions `turf.booleanClockwise` and `turf.rewind` can also be used for that purpose.

Comment: Using also @TomazicM suggestion, I've checked if the polygon was drawn clockwise and I just made the offset negative if so. I've used the solution from stackoverflow.com/a/1165943/4689583 to check for the polygon orientation